# How to create a registering form with apostrophe

Tags: apostrophe-cms

I'm looking for a tutorial to create a register form using Apostrophe.

I've searched on Google and Stack, but didn't find anything interesting.
Could anybody show me the way please (where to start, and what to achieve) ?

Thank you !

Fabien

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I've found the solution, I must call my_modul_name-widgets to access the right route, and it's working fine.
I can add new user to my user list
thank you Joseph

Answer (score 1):

Here's a good example of building a form in Apostrophe that has back-end API components:

https://apostrophecms.org/docs/tutorials/intermediate/forms.html

You would want to replace the back-end code with something like this (inside of your index.js file in your registration module):

```
self.route('post', 'register', function(req, res) {
    var newUser = {
        firstName: req.body['register-first-name'],
        lastName: req.body['register-last-name'],
        email: email,
        password: req.body['register-password'],
        title: req.body['register-first-name'] + ' ' + req.body['register-last-name'],
        published: true,
        username: email
    };

    var userModule = self.apos.modules['apostrophe-users'];

    userModule.insert(req, newUser, {permissions: false}, function (err, res2) {
        if (err) {
            //There was an error - handle it
        } else {
            //User was created
            return res.send({status: 'ok'});
        }
    });
});
```

The code above will put the "register-first-name", "register-last-name" etc. form inputs out of the body of the request and put them into a new object. Then, the userModule.insert call will create a new user in the default Apostrophe User module. On the front end, you would want to find and serialize your form, then initiate a POST request to the route you created above. It might look something like this (replace the {module name} with the correct name of the "registration" module):

```
$('body').on('click', '#register-account', function() {
    var form = $('#user-registration-form');
    var serialized = form.serialize();
    $.post('/modules/{module name}/register', serialized, function(result) {
        //Do something with the result of the registration request
    }
});
```

Then, all that's left is to create the actual page template. The link at the top of this answer has a lot of information about where to create the appropriate Javascript and HTML files to accomplish all of this.

Comment: No problem, Fabien. Next time, it might be better to post follow-up questions as either edits on your original question, or as a new question entirely. It makes it easier for other people to keep track of. Welcome to StackOverflow :)